# Are there any bacteria that can receive ultrasound signals?

Tags: bacteriology, ultrasound

I'm looking for an example of bacteria that could receive ultrasound (at any ultrasound frequency) signal and possibly perform some (re)action afterwards.

Comment: ... well it can break open the cells and kills them ...

Comment: I know but maybe there is some ultrasound frequency that doesn't kill bacteria.

Comment: I'm having a hard time thinking of any natural phenomena that produce ultrasound in which the bacteria could then transduce. If the frequency is not immediately lethal, I worry the heat transfer could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to post a quick answer here, really a thought piece.

Usually to detect a sound wave you need a sounding board about the wavelength of the sound.

Bacteria are on the order of a few microns in length.

[Ultrasound frequencies range from 2 to 200 MHz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrasound) (and up I assume).

[To have a wavelength on the order of 3 microns, a 100 MHz wave would be needed](http://www.mcsquared.com/wavelength.htm).

So only on the very high end of the range.  If bacteria make sound though, they probably are on this frequency range.

I wonder if this has been looked at?  Not sure it has.  While in biology you never say never - if a bacterium really needs to pick up a wave it might have a clever adaptation to do so, but in the 100MHz + frequency range seems more likely.